Short story in which an alien controls two men
This is a short story in which an alien controls two men. Helped by his friend, one man manages to commit suicide and, in revenge, the alien modifies the body of the other man, who then wants to scream, but can't.

In roughly which year did you read this?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Have_No_Mouth,_and_I_Must_Scream? Not an alien, but a malevolent computer

Yes, it has to be. Lou, the alien is a supercomputer and it has trapped two men and two women. It's been identified before in Book: AI controls what is left of humanity, forces people to live in cave and Short story about AI robot who kills all humans except a small group.

Lou, let us know if the story is I Have No Mouth, and I Must Scream so we can mark this as a duplicate.
